# excluding some data while retrieving data from mongodb is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i'm using mongodb nodejs driver.

```
const res = await chats.findOne({ _id: chatId }, { messages: 0, _id: 0 });
```

this is what i'm getting in response, i don't wanna get `messages` and `_id` property on received data

```
{
      "_id": "d0fff742-4af5-4e6a-bd51-9aa47da08fb9",
      "messages": "ea678ca7-81fb-479b-89f8-7995d8831992",
      "lastMessage": {
        "content": "Hey, how's it?",
        "sender": "urtheaman"
      }
    }
  }
```

`collection.find(query, options)`
$slice isn't working as well. i think entire options parameter isn't working.

```
const res = await messages.findOne(
      { _id: messagesId },
      { messages: { $slice: [from, 15] }, _id: 0 }
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use projection like this:

```
var cursor = client
    .db('so')
    .collection('sample')
    .find()
    .project({ _id: 0, messages: 0 });

await cursor.forEach(console.dir); 
// { lastMessage: { content: "Hey, how's it?", sender: 'urtheaman' } }
```

You can see the full sample runnable file [here](https://gist.github.com/newbietek/22be0a64627ce41a7ae3a6d90124c049).

Also, I would suggest that you should use mongoose instead of mongo driver for node for a better development experience.

Comment: i've read on a mongodb articles that mongoose is better for those who are coming from sql background and it limits your capabilities cuz you've to define everything in your models and mongodb is known for asymmetric data storage.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to get the whole document back and then have a function of your own that handles that data in a way that is useful to you.

You could do

```
function getLastMEssage (data){
    return data.lastMessage.content
}
```

Comment: can't mongodb give me only what i want instead of returning the entire document?, in sql we can do it easily and i think it's possible in mongo as well

Comment: I just looked up documentation and you are right.
what happens if you try `{_id: 0, lastMessage: 1}`

Comment: bro, it returns the entire document but i just need some parts of it. `{_id: 0, lastMessage: 1}` or `{_id:1, lastMessage: 1}` both returns the same value i.e. entire document

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
const res = await chats.findOne({ _id: chatId }, { messages: 1, _id: 1 });
```

If you want to have a field, make sure it's one else 0.

Comment: i don't want messages and _id field. (already written above)

Answer (score 0):

### documentation says

*You may specify either fields to include or fields to withhold but not both. For example, the following projection is invalid because it simultaneously includes the name field and withholds the address field*

```json
// Invalid
// Can't simultaneously include and withhold
{ "name": 1, "address": 0 }
```

```json
// Valid
// Can exclude _id while including other fields
{ "_id": 0, "name": 1 }
```

i'm only withholding at a time, not doin both but still doesn't work.